# Google LineChart <undefined> Html tag with html tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I'm using google line charts in my project and I've got a bit of a problem with customizing tooltips.

Fiddle with this problem : http://jsfiddle.net/nq7sk6mq/7/

I want to use HTML tooltips and my chart settings are:

```
if google
  google.load "visualization", "1.0",
    packages: ["corechart"]
    callback: ->
      data = new google.visualization.DataTable()
      data.addColumn('number', ' v1')
      data.addColumn('number', 'v2')
      data.addColumn({type:'boolean',role:'certainty'})
      data.addColumn('number', 'v3')
      data.addColumn({type:'boolean',role:'certainty'})
      data.addColumn('number', 'v4')
      data.addColumn({type:'boolean',role:'certainty'})
      data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip','p':{'html': 'true'}})
```

My data for it:

```
values.push [
          iterator, 
          values2[iterator],
          true, 
          values3[iterator], 
          true, 
          values4[iterator], 
          false,
          customTooltip()]
```

Options:

```
options = {
        legend:{position:"top"},
        vAxes: {
          0: {},
        },
        hAxis: {
          ticks: data.getDistinctValues(0)
        },
        series:{
          0: {pointSize: 5, color: "#0f8d4c"},
          1: {pointSize: 5, color: "#b74848"},
          2: {color: "#00a259", pointSize: 4}
        },

        width : width,
        tooltip: {isHtml: true}
      }
```

call the draw:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart(values,chartid,options))
drawChart: (data, chartid,options) ->
  chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(chartid));
  chart.draw(data,options)
```

customTooltip:

```
customTooltip: () ->
return '<div style="padding:5px 5px 5px 5px; height:20px;">' +
  "<p>Teeest</p>"+
'</div>'
```

And I get in Chrome:

```
<div>
  <undefined class="google-visualization-tooltip" style="width: 66px; height: 20px; left: 181.5px; top: 133.5px;">
    <div style="padding:5px 5px 5px 5px; height:20px;">
      <p>Teeest</p>
    </div>
  </undefined>
</div>
```

Charts are displayed correctly and, if using normal tooltips, they also works correctly. So my question is why do I get this undefined tag which is destroying the tooltip layout?

I found that not only I am the person who encountered this problem.http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1290

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm new to jsfiddle and i have problem with it (was looking on working examples but mine is somehow wrong could You check it ?) http://jsfiddle.net/nq7sk6mq/4/

Comment: @ciuuable here: http://jsfiddle.net/nq7sk6mq/5/

Comment: Thank You mate, Here is fiddle with exact problem i have
http://jsfiddle.net/nq7sk6mq/7/

Comment: @cisuuble try removing the `line-height: 300px;` from your chart_div css

Comment: No problem, good luck with your proyect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @juvian help The problem was that styling was set inline on div cointainer and it seems that tooltips inherited it from div. So the answer is to remove the styling from div container and apply it to the desired element.